# how to select only one checkbox at a time in Angular 9 with ngFor

Tags: angular, angular8, angular9

Am displaying data from database into a checkbox in Angular 9 for user to be able to select one checkbox or more but am seeing an abnormal situation where if I click one checkbox, all get selected instead of only the one I clicked. Please any help on this?
Below is my code..

```
<label for=" Option" *ngFor="let mc of  ChooseCriteria " class="form-control" >
        <input type="checkbox" name="Option" [value]="mc.id"  (change)='selectOption($event)' [(ngModel)]=" OptionValue" >{{mc.category}}<br> 
 </label>
```

Comment: You probably should iterate not in label tag, but make another e.g. 'p' or 'div' tag, and pass to your function 'selectOption' despite $event also id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happening because, you're using same `ngModel` for all checkbox, that will bind the `value(boolean)` to all inputs automatically, which is resulting `selecting` all. To fix this, you should be using separate `ngModel` for each checkbox.

Example: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-0-0-rc-1-ke5jcx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
// component.
ChooseCriteria = [
  { category: "Fruits", id: 1, checked: false },
  { category: "Animals", id: 2, checked: false }
];

<div>
 <span>{{ ChooseCriteria | json }}</span>
 <label for=" Option" *ngFor="let mc of ChooseCriteria" class="form-control" > 
  <input type="checkbox" name="Option" [(ngModel)]="mc.checked"> 
  {{ mc.category }}
 </label>
</div>
```